# VIM search and replace: change string before replace

Tags: regex, search, vim, replace

I need to replace several lines in a PHP file like the following (this is only an example but it represents the real problem):

```
<?php

$errors = array(
    'error_1',
    'error_2',
    'error_3',
    'error_4',
    'error_5',
);
```

I want to make them an associative array, no problem with that:

```
:%s/'\(.\+\)',/'\1' => '\1',/g
```

And I will get the following output:

```
<?php

$errors = array(
    'error_1' => 'error_1',
    'error_2' => 'error_2',
    'error_3' => 'error_3',
    'error_4' => 'error_4',
    'error_5' => 'error_5',
);
```

But the problem is: I want to remove the underscore from the array values (the keys have to contain undescores), is there a way that I can replace underscores for white-spaces before replacing with \1?

That's the output that I want:

```
<?php

$errors = array(
    'error_1' => 'error 1',
    'error_2' => 'error 2',
    'error_3' => 'error 3',
    'error_4' => 'error 4',
    'error_5' => 'error 5',
);
```

Comment: Do they all start with `error_`?

Comment: You could use `submatch`, as explained by @Marth; but you should first simplify your original regex, e.g., `%s/\('.\+'\)\zs,/ => \1,/g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
%s/\v'(.+)'/\="'" . submatch(1) . "' => '" . substitute(submatch(1), "_", " ", "g") . "'"
```

`\=` starts a 'sub-replace-expression' (see `:h sub-replace-\=`) in which you use `submatch(1)` to access `\1`, and `substitute()` (see `:h substitute()`) to replace "_" by " " in its second occurrence (change `"g"` to `""` if you only want to substitute the first `"_"` occurrence in `\1`).

---

Capturing the surrounding single quotes in `\1` makes the replace part *a bit* easier to read :

```
:%s/\v('.+')/\=submatch(1) . " => " . substitute(submatch(1), "_", " ", "g")
```

---

Of course if the pattern is simple enough, Two-Bit Alchemist's solution is probably faster/easier to use/remember.

Comment: wouldn't it be better if you put a `g` flag?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: It doesn't appear to be necessary in OP's question (also the real reason is that I've had `gdefault` on for so long that I pretty much always forget about it when I answer a question).

Comment: I just had to add the 'g' flag and then it worked like a charm. The actual strings are a little more complex than error_, like: "error_cannot_read_file_from_provided_path". Thank you so much!

Comment: @user2937998: I'm guessing you mean the `g` flag in the `substitute()` call, which I just realized is probably what @HuStmpHrrr meant too. I'll edit my answer and add it to it.

Answer (score 2):

If they all start with `error_`, just use that:

```
%s/'error_\(\d\)'/'error_\1' => 'error \1'/g
```

Otherwise if all you can work with is the underscore, you'll just have to define a pattern for that as well and capture 2 groups:

```
%s/'\(\w\+\)_\(\d\)'/'\1_\2' => '\1 \2'/g
```